# Solving recursive formulas, proving with induction

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I thought I had the answer to this problem but I seem to be off, something is wrong.

The prompt:

> Find the exact solution to the following recursive formulas. You may guess the solution and then prove it by induction.
>
> $T(1) = 1$ and $T(n) = T(n-1) + (2n-1)$

Working out the first few in the series: 
$T(2) = 4$
$T(3) = 9$
$T(4) = 16$

So I would assume the formula is $T(n) = n^2$

To prove by induction the base case (1) works out, since $1^2 = 1$. Then if I assume $T(n) = n^2$, I try to prove:

$T(n+1) = (n+1)^2$
$T(n) + (2n-1) = (n+1)(n+1)$
$n^2 + 2n-1=n^2+2n+1$

That obviously doesn't add up, so where'd I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since
$T(n)
=T(n-1)+2n-1
$,
replacing $n$
by $n+1$,
this becomes
$T(n+1)
=T(n)+2(n+1)-1
=T(n)+2n+1
$.

This makes your induction work,
because
$T(n)+2n+1
=n^2+2n+1
=(n+1)^2
=T(n+1)
$.

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong. I substituted $T(n+1)$ with $T(n) +2n -1$ but it should have been $T(n) + 2n$, or as you suggest, just plug in $n+1$ into $T(n)$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have
$$T(n+1)=T(n)+2(\color{red}{n+1})-1$$
in the inductive step.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typing error as I attempted to enter this question. Edited, what you see now is correct.